# bwu-datagrid - is it broken in current polymer release?

Tags: dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

It would appear that bwu_datagrid is broken in the recent polymer release as none of my grids are rendered after upgrading. Could you confirm if this is so?

Comment: I'll take a look the next days.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried all examples (Dartium, Chrome) and can't reproduce your problem (Polymer 0.15.3+2).

Maybe you run into an issue like this https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/reviews/KW8P4ZOcfIA which refers https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/pull/57 (I couldn't finde more information about the actual problem they are facing there but seems to be CSS and Polmyer > 0.15.2)